# How to filter data converted from xml to php objects using php?

Tags: php, xml, jquery-selectbox

How to display the array in html select box, i want to filter the data in filters with different parameters.

```
$xml_feed_url = 'http://www.propertyfinder.ae/upload/xmlfeed/xml-feed-
example.xml';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);   



function produce_XML_object_tree($raw_XML) {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     try {
       $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($raw_XML);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
    // Something went wrong.
       $error_message = 'SimpleXMLElement threw an exception.';
         foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error_line) {
        $error_message .= "\t" . $error_line->message;
        }
        trigger_error($error_message);
        return false;
      }
   return $xmlTree;
 }
 $feed = produce_XML_object_tree($xml);
```

Comment: @PhilippMaurer sorry for that i am beginner to xml feeds, ll explain my question in detail here .

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) articles.

Comment: can you please help me out now, i updated my question @PhilippMaurer

Comment: From the programmatical side your question looks great now :-) To provide an answer I yet need to know what you are trying to do with the data you get. For example: What is the condition that the elements have to fullfill? What is your desrired output?  Right now its just clear that you successfully made an PHP object out of your XML feed, but what you want to do with it is unclear. (Beside that you want to filter it, which depends on the use case :-) )

Comment: I want to display the array in dropdown according to each node,                      Location, Price , and property type , each in separate dropdown list... @PhilippMaurer

Comment: @PhilippMaurer here is the live example you can check in the filter http://www.hausandhaus.com/property-sales/1-bedroom-apartments-for-sale-in-dubai-between-500000-and-750000